# Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.Location of the Android SDK has not been set up in the preferences

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]

I have used these

Install New Software ---> Add

Inside Add Repository write the Name: ADT (or, as you want)

and Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

after loading some time you will get Developer Tools.

check Developer Tool

click Next

Finish

but i get these error :

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Android DDMS 23.0.7.2120684 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.feature.group 23.0.7.2120684)
Software currently installed: Android DDMS 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group

what is solution for this problem  ?

Comment: why you are still using adt with eclipse and not android studio

Comment: actually i have installed android after a long time.

Comment: try android studio it is very less hectic than eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You should **remove old adt** before install new one.

The only way to remove the ADT plugin from Eclipse is to go to `Help > About Eclipse/About ADT > Installation Details.`

Select a plug-in you want to uninstall, then click `Uninstall...` button at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have existing copy of Android sdk tools, if yes then uninstall it then install it back using above instructions